# What is the metric tensor on the n-sphere (hypersphere)?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, spherical-geometry

I am considering the unit sphere (but an extension to one of radius $r$ would be appreciated) centered at the origin. Any coordinate system will do, though the standard angular one (with 1 radial and $n-1$ angular coordinates) would be preferable.

I know that on the 2-sphere we have $ds^2 = d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d\phi^2$ (in spherical coordinates) but I'm not sure how this generalizes to $n$ dimensions.

Added note: If anything can be discovered only about the determinant of the tensor (when presented in matrix form), that would also be quite helpful.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I will define the metric of $S^{n-1}$ via pullback of the Euclidean metric on ${\mathbb{R}}^{n}$.

To start with we take $n$-dimension Cartesian co-ordinates:
$(x_1,x_2......x_n)$.
The metric here is $g_{ij }= \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta.

We specify the surface patches of  $S^{n-1}$ by the parametrization  $f$:
$$x_1=r{\cos{\phi_1}},$$

$$x_p=r{\cos{\phi_p}}{\Pi_{m=1}^{p-1}}{\sin{\phi_{m}}},$$

$$x_n=r{\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}}{\sin{\phi_{m}}},$$

Where $r$ is the radius of the hypersphere and the angles have the usual range.

We see that the pullback of the Euclidean metric $g'_{ab} = (f^*g)_{ab}$ is the metric tensor of the hypersphere. Its components are:

$$g'_{ab} = g_{ij} {\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{\phi_a}}} {\frac{\partial{x_j}}{\partial{\phi_b}}} = {\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{\phi_a}}}{\frac{\partial{x_i}}{\partial{\phi_b}}}$$

We get $2$ cases here:

i) $a>b$ or $b>a$, For these components one obtains a series of terms with alternating signs which vanishes, $g'_{ab}=0$ and thus all off-diagonal components of the tensor vanish.

ii) $a=b$,

$$g'_{11}={r^2}$$

$$g'_{aa} ={r^2} \prod_{m=1}^{a-1} \sin^2{\phi_{m}}$$
where $2\leq a\leq {n-1}$

The determinant is very straightforward to calculate:

$$ \det{(g'_{ab})} = {r^2} \prod_{m=1}^{n-1} g'_{mm}$$

Finally, we can write the metric of the hypersphere as:

$$g' = {r^2} \, d\phi_{1}\otimes d\phi_{1} +  {r^2} \sum_{a=2}^{n-1} \left( \prod_{m=1}^{a-1} \sin^2{\phi_{m}} \right) d\phi_{a} \otimes d\phi_{a} $$

Comment: Great, thanks for the step-by-step explanation. Although what you've written is fairly clear, you can make it clearer by using the TeX environment, with the `$` delimiters, like instead of g'rϕk, write `$g'_{r\phi_k}$`, which comes out as $g'_{r\phi_k}$.

Comment: This is a very good answer and very useful too, as it is not that easy to find this piece of information on the net. Proper formatting would make it great.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Done. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It seems $g'_{11}=r^2$, no?

Comment: Can somebody explain more thoroughly why the off diagonal terms vanish?

Comment: @gamebm yes I think so, I have submitted the edit. thanks

Answer (score 17):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$For posterity: Fix $r > 0$, and let $S^{n}(r)$ denote the sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin in $\Reals^{n+1}$. Stereographic projection from the north pole $N = (0, \dots, 0, 1)$ on the *unit* sphere $S^{n} = S^{n}(1)$ defines a diffeomorphism $\Pi_{N}:S^{n} \setminus \{N\} \to \Reals^{n}$ given in Cartesian coordinates by
\begin{align*}
\Pi_{N}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}, x_{n+1}) &= \frac{1}{1 - x_{n+1}}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}), \\
\Pi_{N}^{-1}(t_{1}, \dots, t_{n}) &= \frac{(2t_{1}, \dots, 2t_{n}, \|t\|^{2} - 1)}{\|t\|^{2} + 1}.
\end{align*}
In these coordinates, the induced (round) metric on the unit sphere is well-known (and easily checked) to be conformally-Euclidean:
$$
g(t) = \frac{4 (dt_{1}^{2} + \cdots + dt_{n}^{2})}{(\|t\|^{2} + 1)^{2}}.
$$

Stereographic projection from the north pole $(0, \dots, 0, r)$ of $S^{n}(r)$ is given by the scaled mapping $x \mapsto t = r\Pi_{N}(x/r)$, whose inverse is $t \mapsto x = r\Pi_{N}^{-1}(t/r)$, i.e.,
\begin{align*}
r\Pi_{N}(x_{1}/r, \dots, x_{n}/r, x_{n+1}/r) &= \frac{1}{r - x_{n+1}}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}), \\
r\Pi_{N}^{-1}(t_{1}/r, \dots, t_{n}/r) &= \frac{\bigl(2t_{1}, \dots, 2t_{n}, r(\|t/r\|^{2} - 1)\bigr)}{\|t/r\|^{2} + 1}.
\end{align*}
The induced metric in these coordinates is consequently
$$
r^{2} g(t/r) = \frac{4 (dt_{1}^{2} + \cdots + dt_{n}^{2})}{(\|t/r\|^{2} + 1)^{2}}
= \frac{4r^{4} (dt_{1}^{2} + \cdots + dt_{n}^{2})}{(\|t\|^{2} + r^{2})^{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

As asked in a comment by Ivan Burbano, here are more details about $g'_{ab}=0$ for $a\neq b$ in orange_soda's answer. Without loss of generality, assume $1\leq a<b\leq n-1$. Note that
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{\partial x_p}{\partial \phi_a}=-r\delta_{pa}\sin\phi_a\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin\phi_m+r\cos\phi_p\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin\phi_m\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\dfrac{\delta_{ma}\cos\phi_m}{\sin\phi_m}\right),\quad \forall1<p<n
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\dfrac{\partial x_n}{\partial \phi_a}=r\dfrac{\cos\phi_a}{\sin\phi_a}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin\phi_m,
\end{equation*}
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) and I used the [product rule for more than two factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Product_of_more_than_two_factors). Also, we can see that $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \phi_b}=0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,b-1$. Then,
\begin{align*}
g'_{ab}&=\sum_{p=b}^{n-1}\left[r\cos\phi_p\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin\phi_m\right)\left(\sum_{m=1}^{p-1}\dfrac{\delta_{ma}\cos\phi_m}{\sin\phi_m}\right)\right]\dfrac{\partial x_p}{\partial\phi_b}+r^2\dfrac{\cos\phi_a\cos\phi_b}{\sin\phi_a\sin\phi_b}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin^2\phi_m\\
&=r\dfrac{\cos\phi_a}{\sin\phi_a}\left[\sum_{p=b}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin\phi_m\right)\cos\phi_b\dfrac{\partial x_p}{\partial\phi_b}+r\dfrac{\cos\phi_b}{\sin\phi_b}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right].
\end{align*}
Dividing the sum $\sum_{p=b}^{n-1}$ into $p=b$ and $\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-1}$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
g'_{ab}&=r^2\dfrac{\cos\phi_a}{\sin\phi_a}\left[-\sin\phi_b\cos\phi_b\prod_{m=1}^{b-1}\sin^2\phi_m+\dfrac{\cos\phi_b}{\sin\phi_b}\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-1}\cos^2\phi_p\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right)+\dfrac{\cos\phi_b}{\sin\phi_b}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right]\\
&=r^2\dfrac{\cos\phi_a\cos\phi_b}{\sin\phi_a\sin\phi_b}\left[-\prod_{m=1}^b\sin^2\phi_m+\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-1}\cos^2\phi_b\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right)+\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right].
\end{align*}
On the other hand, by $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-1}\cos^2\phi_b\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right)+\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\sin^2\phi_m&=\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-2}\cos^2\phi_b\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right)+\prod_{m=1}^{n-2}\sin^2\phi_m\\
&=\sum_{p=b+1}^{n-3}\cos^2\phi_b\left(\prod_{m=1}^{p-1}\sin^2\phi_m\right)+\prod_{m=1}^{n-3}\sin^2\phi_m\\
&\quad\vdots\\
&=\prod_{m=1}^b\sin^2\phi_m.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we conclude $g'_{ab}=0$.